# How does the 3.3V output work in this PSU circuit?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, how-does-it-work

I am trying to understand how computer PSUs work.
I found the following circuit in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#+3.3_V_and_+5_V_rails) and I noticed that, unlike the 12V and 5V outputs, there is no winding in the transformer for the 3.3V output. Instead, a coil is connected to the 5V secondary before the diode.

I have some experience in swith mode power supplies but I did not see this circuit before.
How does this 3.3V output circuit work?

[image: Principal circuit diagram of a PC power supply]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quite complete explanation of how the 3.3V voltage regulation works in this old post: [Unconventional voltage regulation scheme in the secondary of an ATX power supply, how does it work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222466/unconventional-voltage-regulation-scheme-in-the-secondary-of-an-atx-power-supply)

Answer (score 1):

That's a simplified diagram how a power supply might work - not how all power supplies work.

Quote how it works from the Wikipedia article you linked :

> In the most common design this voltage is generated by shifting and transforming the pulses of the 5 V rail on an additional choke, causing the voltage to rise delayed and rectified separately into a dedicated 3.3 V rail and getting the rising idle voltage cut by a device type TL431, which behaves similar to a zener diode.

Comment: I am specially interested in this circuit because it is something new to me and I am curious about it.
I also read the article in Wikipedia but it is still not clear to me how these 3.3V are achieve...
Any application note or technical article will be greatly appreciated.